# My location based app works on android 4.2.2 but not on 4.0.3 or 4.0.4

Tags: android

I searched, searched and searched, but couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I have a very simple location based which returns the person's current address.
When you open the app in a 4.2.2 device, a GPS icon on the notification bar appears and when you press My Location button the address is returned.

But when running the app in a 4.0.3 and 4.0.4 the GPS icon is not shown on the notification bar and when clicking on My Location the app closes.

I'm new to android development so I have no idea why this is happening.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix it?

Thanks.

This is part of my manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATIO" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Part of the code:

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ActivityConstants {

```
private static final long MIN_DIST_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; //in meters
private static final long MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 0; //in milliseconds
protected LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;
Criteria criteria;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager=LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, MIN_DIST_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, new MyLocationListener());

}


public void myLocation(View view) {


    Location location =locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    // If location is not null show a Toast with the location.
    if (location != null) {
        String message = String.format("Current location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s", location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Latitude and longitude were not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            String address = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";

            }

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your current address is: \n" + address, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nickolaus. On the emulator the app works fine on 4.0.4. The problem is on the device. How would I get de log from the device?

Comment: if you connect your device via usb you can use usb-debugging

Comment: [2013-02-17 02:44:46 - com.eric.android.loneworker] Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.eric.android.loneworker' on port 8600

Comment: this is not an error-log

Comment: Hi Nickolaus. There are no errors. The apps opens on the device. It doesn't crash when trying to get the Provider, but at the same time it doesn't show the GPS icon on the notification bar. I tried a third-party app that requires GPS and the icon shows up. Is there any special call for android 4.0.3/4?

Comment: have you tested your devices gps sensor with an other app, maybe there is an error with your gps sensor, or its driver(s)

Comment: Yes I tried with StaySafe app and the icon appears.

Comment: Just added part of the code in the question.